# pip cant install radiopy

Tags: python, installation, pip

I've tried
`pip install radiopy`

*Traceback:*

```
C:\Users\олег\Downloads>pip install radiopy
Collecting radiopy
Using cached radio

py-0.6.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\29F0~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-blxa2oob\radiopy\setup.py, line 23, in <module>
version=get_version('radio.py'),
File "C:\Users\29F0~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-blxa2oob\radiopy\setup.py
return __version__
NameError: name '__version__' is not defined
----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in       
C:\Users\29F0~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-blxa2oob\radiopy\
```

I've also tried:
`easy_install radiopy`

*Traceback:*

```
File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 168, in save_modules 
saved_exc.resume()
File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 143, in resume
six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\_vendor\six.py", line 685, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 156, in save_modules
yield saved
File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 197, in setup_context  yield
File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 246, in run_setup
DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 276, in run return func()
File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 245, in runner
_execfile(setup_script, ns)
File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 47, in _execfile

exec(code, globals, locals)
File "C:\Users\29F0~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-laprrvio\radiopy-0.6\setup.py", line 23, in <module>
File "C:\Users\29F0~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-laprrvio\radiopy-0.6\setup.py", line 19, in get_version
NameError: name '__version__' is not defined
```

Lately,
`C:\Users\олег>pip install C:\\Users\\олег\\Downloads\\radiopy-0.6.tar.gz`

*Traceback:*

```
C:\Users\олег>pip install C:\\Users\\олег\\Downloads\\radiopy-0.6.tar.gz
Processing c:\users\олег\downloads\radiopy-0.6.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\29F0~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-8evw0uk0-build\setup.py", line 23, in <module>
version=get_version('radio.py'),
File "C:\Users\29F0~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-8evw0uk0-build\setup.py", line 19, in get_version
return __version__
NameError: name '__version__' is not defined
----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\29F0~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-8evw0uk0-build\
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The module seems to support Python 2 only. The `setup.py` contains a very dubious hack to evaluate the `__version__` variable:

```
def get_version(filename):
    """Extract __version__ from file by parsing it."""
    with open(filename) as fp:
        for line in fp:
            if line.startswith('__version__'):
                exec(line)
                return __version__
```

What this does is to find a line that starts with `__version__`, namely `__version__ = '0.6'`, and then execute it as dynamic code with `exec`, which works. However in Python 3 this *doesn't* modify local variables and thus `__version__` is not defined on the next line.

Even if you fixed this bug, you'd met a countless others as the package is not Python-3-ready at all. The easiest solution would be to use Python 2. But even then I am not too sure if this works correctly on Windows as it is written for the `mplayer`/`mencoder` suite, and seems to be very Linux/POSIX minded in its code.

Comment: It definitely doesn't work in Python 3, and wouldn't without loads of fixes. Do you even have [this mplayer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mplayerwin/) on your Windows? Even then I'd personally not waste time installing Python 2 and trying this, but I am not forbidding you :D